# How can I create a text file on an SD card mounted on an Arduino Yun?

Tags: arduino, text-files, sd-card, arduino-yun

Like the title says, I am trying to create a text file from my Arduino sketch. My Arduino is connected to my computer via an Ethernet cable but the SD card is mounted on the Arduino, so I am assuming the connection to the computer (USB or Ethernet) does not matter. What I've found on the [official Arduino documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ReadWrite) seems pretty straightforward, but yet I can't get to create the file.

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <Bridge.h>
#include <Console.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

File myFile;

void setup() {
  // Start using the Bridge.
  Bridge.begin();
  // To output on the Serial Monitor
  Console.begin();
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  if (!SD.begin(4)) {
    Console.println("initialization failed!");
    //return;
  }
  Console.println("initialization done.");
  myFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE);
  if (myFile) {
    Console.print("Writing to test.txt...\n");
    myFile.println("testing 1, 2, 3.");
    // close the file:
    myFile.close();
    Console.print("done.\n");
  } else {
    // if the file didn't open, print an error:
    Console.print("error opening test.txt\n");
  }
  // re-open the file for reading:
  myFile = SD.open("test.txt");
  if (myFile) {
    Console.print("test.txt: ");
    // read from the file until there's nothing else in it:
    while (myFile.available()) {
      Console.print(myFile.read());
    }
    // close the file:
    myFile.close();
  } else {
    // if the file didn't open, print an error:
    Console.print("error opening test.txt\n");
  }
}

void loop() {
  Console.print("Loop\n");
  delay(1000);
}
```

And this is the output:

```
initialization failed!
initialization done.
error opening test.txterror opening test.txt
Loop
[...]
Loop
```

As opposed to the link I provided above, I am using `Console` instead of `Serial` for the print statements. The rest is the same. And I obviously have an SD card mounted.

Any idea anyone?

Comment: Have you formated the SD? In which type?

Comment: I did, it's FAT32.

Comment: I've also already used it to update the Arduino's software and after an ssh into the Arduino I can see that the directory /mnt/sda1/ still contains that file. I can create even create files from Terminal using nano so the SD card is definitely working well.

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/YunDatalogger

Comment: Try creating a folder inside the SD and the path to the file folder/test.txt. Maybe there's something with root permissions, since you've used it with update files, idk

Comment: @gre_gor The YunDatalogger sketch is stuck on the setup(), more precisely on the while (!SerialUSB) . That line makes sure that the USB connection with my computer is working, right? But I am connected to the Arduino using an Ethernet cable and using a USB connection is not an option in my particular case.
@ GeorgeRappel I've tried, I can create the files but the sketch still won't open them.

Comment: Just remove it and fix the code to print to `Console`.

Comment: @gre_gor I've commented out that line in the setup and the file finally got created. I also had to change the path from /mnt/sd/ to /mnt/sda1/. I'll write a proper answer tomorrow, but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by gre_gor in the comments I followed this tutorial specifically for the Arduino Yun: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/YunDatalogger. I had to change the path to the file on the SD card (mine was '/mnt/sda1/myFile.txt') and I had to delete these two lines in the setup function:

```
// Delete these two lines:
while (!SerialUSB); // wait for Serial port to connect.
SerialUSB.println("Filesystem datalogger\n");
```

And it worked.